# Does Ansible Jinja2 Templating support list arguments in for loop?

Tags: ansible, jinja2, monit

I'm trying to dynamically create a template from a list and I'm wondering if Ansible supports something like

```yaml
{% for server in [sg-bend1, sg-bend2] %}
check program {{ server }}_test
  with path /home/ubuntu/t.sh {{ server }}
  if status != 0 then alert
{% endfor %}
```

theoretically this should produce

```bash
check program sg-bend1_test
  with path /home/ubuntu/t.sh sg-bend1
  if status != 0 then alert

check program sg-bend2_test
  with path /home/ubuntu/t.sh sg-bend2
  if status != 0 then alert
```

Comment: Yes, it does, have you tested it? What errors does it yields you? (At a first glance, I would say that `[sg-bend1, sg-bend2]` should be `['sg-bend1', 'sg-bend2']`, as those two should strings, not variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the provided description I understand your question is related to [Jinja2 Templating](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/) and syntax only.

One approach you could try is the following

```yaml
{% for i in range(1,3) %}
check program sg-bend{{ i }}_test
  with path /home/ubuntu/t.sh sg-bend{{ i }}
  if status != 0 then alert
{% endfor %}
```

**Similar Q&A**

- [How to make a for loop in Jinja?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29706099/)
- [... table with Jinja2 and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40362367/6771046)
- [How can I test Jinja2 templates in Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35407822/)

**Documentation**

- [Jinja2 Template Designer Documentation - List of Control Structures](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#list-of-control-structures)

As far as I understand the documentation the solution should be to provide the list in a variable

```yaml
{% for SERVER in SERVERS %}`
```

or an other syntax

```yaml
{% for SERVER in ('test1', 'test2') %}
```

**Example**

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    SERVERS: ['test1', 'test2']

  tasks:

  - name: Show result
    debug:
      msg: "{% for SERVER in SERVERS %}{{ SERVER }}{% endfor %}"

  - name: Show result
    debug:
      msg: "{% for SERVER in ('test1', 'test2') %}{{ SERVER }}{% endfor %}"
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Show result] ******
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: test1test2

TASK [Show result] ******
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: test1test2
```

Comment: this indeed work. Thanks.